# Mission: sections deleting :)

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, animation

I have code below where I try delete rows. When row is not last in section all is ok, but when it is last one in section - app is crashed

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        if let item = shopList.getItem(index: indexPath) {
            shopTableView.beginUpdates()

            let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
            indexSet.add(indexPath.section - 1)
            shopTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            //shopTableView.deleteSections(indexSet as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)



            shopList.remove(item: item)

            shopTableView.endUpdates()

        }
    }
}
```

I got error

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid >number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view >after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in >the table view before the update (2), plus or minus the number of sections >inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Is there standard way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code on below and it works

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        if let item = shopList.getItem(index: indexPath) {
            shopTableView.beginUpdates()
            let sectionStatus = shopList.remove(item: item)
            shopTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            if sectionStatus == .sectionEmpty  {
                let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section)
                shopTableView.deleteSections(indexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            }
            shopTableView.endUpdates()
            totalLabel.update(value: shopList.total)

        }
    }

}
```